# jQuery pass dynamically created variable to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have form partial in Rails, laid out like so:

```
<div class"row">
    <div class="col-md-6" id="top_level">               
    </div>
</div>

<div class"row">
    <div class="col-md-2" id="sub_category1">               
    </div>
</div>  

<div class"row">
    <div class="col-md-2" id="sub_category2">               
    </div>
</div>

<div class"row">
    <div class="col-md-2" id="sub_category3">               
    </div>
</div>

<div class"row">
    <div class="col-md-3" id="sub_category4">               
    </div>
</div>  

    <div class"row">
        <div class="col-md-3" id="sub_category5">               
        </div>
    </div>
```

It is for selecting categories and sub-categories of items.

listings_controller:

```
def new
  @product_listing = Listing.new
  @product_ = Product.find(params[:product_id])  
  # gon.categories = EbayCategory.all
  gon.top_level = EbayCategory.top_level
end
```

In the model:

```
scope :top_level, -> { where('category_id = parent_id').order(:id) }
```

Each category record (17989 of them) has a unique category_id, and a parent_id.  As indicated above, the top level category_id = the parent_id for the same record. All the subcategories have their own category_ids, which are the parent_ids of the next level down, and so on, varying between 1 and 5 sub-levels.

I've tried a cascade of view files, which works fine (it renders the correct categories and sub-categories) but I can't pass the listing id that way because I don't know how to transmit 2 ids (one for the parent category, one for the listing id) through the params hash using the link_to url helper, so I lose the id for the listing I'm trying to create while navigating all the sub-categories.

So I'm trying it with jQuery, using the Gon gem.  Not only does this mean loading the entire db table (about 7 MB, once I un-comment the line for use in level 2 thru 5) into ram, but I can't figure out how to pass the category_id from the dynamically created top_level list when one of its elements is clicked.  There are many levels to go, but right now I'm just trying to console.log the category_id for ONE level, so I can see that it's registering. So far unsuccessful, after trying many different syntaxes and methods, of which this is the latest:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(gon.top_level).each(function(){   
$("#top_level").append('<h5><a href="#">' + this.main_category + " >"  + '</a></h5>').data($(this).category_id);            
    })  

$("#top_level").on('click', 'a', function(){
    console.log($(this).data());
});     

</script>
```

...returns

```
Object {}
```

to the console.

Any suggestions on how to store ids dynamically with the text category titles?

Comment: Read up on how to *correctly* use the [.data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method. In any case, an alternative would be to use a closure or even per-ID lookup

Answer (score 1):

```
$('gon.top_level').each(function(){   
    var lnk = $('<h5><a href="#">' + this.main_category + " >"  + '</a></h5>')
                  .find('a').data({'category':$(this).category_id,'anotherKey':'value'});   

    $("#top_level").append(lnk);         
}); 

$("#top_level").on('click', 'a', function(){
    console.log($(this).data('category'));
    console.log($(this).data('anotherKey'));
});
```

To set data use `$(elment).data({key:value});`

To get data use `$(elment).data(key);`